# Jquery broken by GetResponse (email marketing) web form script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a site that relies on quite a bit of javascript. The problem is, I'm not a javascript guru in the least. Yes, bit off more than I can chew, here.

I'm using jquery for a spy effect, and use GetResponse for email signups.

If I implement my GetResponse script, it breaks the area later in the page which depends on the jquery script. Pull the GetResponse script and it works just fine.

Problem is, I need them both. ;)

The trick, I suppose, is that the GetResponse script is actually another Jquery script, so it's getting called twice...

Any help?

The site is http://djubi.com/testserver
Check out (urlabove)/nogetresponsescript.php to see it work without the GetResponse script. You should be able to see all the source just fine.

Thanks everyone. jf

Comment: java and javascript are totally, completely different things (just for future reference)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to be more careful with my terminology.

Comment: Any thoughts, Pointy, on how to fix this gig (other than errant spaces in words, dramatically altering the meaning - javacript vs java script). Oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetResponse includes jQuery and is overwriting your plugin ($.fn.simpleSpy) when it loads jQuery again. So what you can try to do is wrap your plugin and initialization in $(document).ready(). For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function($) {
    $.fn.simpleSpy = function (limit, interval) {
      // snipping code out
    };
   })(jQuery);

  $(function() {
    $('ul.spy').simpleSpy();
  });
});
```

I pasted your code for simpleSpy into Firebug after the page loaded, and it seemed to work. If **$(document).ready()** doesn't work, you might want to try **$(window).load()**.

Comment: Excellent. $(window).load() worked! It does lag a bit to get the script running when the page is first loaded, but it works. Yeah. Thank you for the help!

Comment: This is my first time here, so I can't vote up your response. I'm sorry, is there anything I can do as such a n ew user? I'd like to give you props.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with $(window).load() is that it waits for everything to load (including the scripts that GetResponse puts in.. jQuery!), so it does have a bit of a delay.

The real issue is that GetResponse should be check to see if jQuery exists BEFORE putting those scripts into the page. Unfortunately, you have no control over that.

I'm not sure what new user abilities are available.. it's been a while since I first signed up! haha